# Cannot map an array outside of the useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting an error in the console as follows:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

I've searched online extensively for the past few hours and all the solutions state that the async call isn't defined and that's why no value is passed to the map. Thing is, it is defined and called with an empty object to force the await. Please could somebody let me know what I'm missing in the below code?

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
const getProduct = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await publicRequest.get("products/find/" + id);
    setProduct(res.data);
  } catch (err) {}
};
getProduct();

 }, [id]);
```

This gets a 'Product' object, which contains an array field called colour. I use this to display several options on the page.

```
{product.colour.map((c) => (
            <FilterColor colour={c} key={c} />
          ))}
```

When I change the use effect code to console log the res.data.colour, I get the colour values. I don't understand why this map throws this undefined error, when the product is defined as a result of the setProduct call.

I hope someone can help :)

***Edit: Other bits of code that will help understanding of the above:***

```
export const publicRequest = axios.create({  baseURL: BASE_URL,});
```

and this is how I get console.log to display the colours, by changing the useeffect section:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getProduct = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await publicRequest.get("products/find/" + id);
        setProduct(res.data);
        console.log(res.data.colour); //this displays an array of colours in the console
      } catch (err) {}
    };
    getProduct();
  }, [id]);
```

and without using the map() function, I can display data like this: `<Title>{product.title}</Title>`

Comment: `publicRequest` Where is this defined?

Comment: `setProduct.colour.map`, I've a feeling you meant to do `product.colour.map`

Comment: setProduct is a function. Use product.colour instead

Comment: Also you might want to do -> `useState({color: []});` to make sure your first render doesn't error, or do a null check on the render.

Comment: @Keith sorry that was a mistake with my copying and pasting! I tried setProduct after using product initially. Neither options work. Also, useState({color: []}); didn't help unfortunately. Same error occurs and, additionally, I need other properties to be set, such as product.title etc. These values do work, it's just when I use map() that the error is displayed.

Comment: Yeah, sorry it should have been `useState({colour: []})` Your using the correct spelling, I'm so used to American color these days.. :)   And yes, if you have mutliple things in the state I much prefer the null check.. eg.. `useState(null);`, and then in your render. -> `if (!product) return null`..

Comment: @Keith Thanks so much for your help here. Using part of your suggestion and Vishnu's suggestion solved the issue. After nearly three hours of trying to solve it myself! Have a great day both!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because, when first the page is rendered which is before the api fetch has actually completed, your product value is `{}`, so when you do `product.colour.map` since it doesn't have any `colour` property you will get  `Cannot read properties of undefined`  error.

So what you need to do is either

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState({colour: []});
```

or in your map do

```
{product?.colour.map((c) => (
        <FilterColor colour={c} key={c} />
      ))}
```

Comment: Using both the ? and the {colour: []} worked for me. Using them separately didn't work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you are using `?` you can avoid setting `colour` in useState, you can do `useState({});` and it will still work. :)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It only works when I use both the ? and stating colour[] in the useState. Possibly because I have multiple arrays as part of the object?

Comment: ah - it works for me if I add the ? after colour. So product.colour?.map() works

Comment: Do `product?.colour?.map` then.